# What is the equation for the least amount of clues needed for a sudoku puzzle related to size?

Tags: puzzle

What is the least amount of hints a sudoku puzzle needs to be solved related to size $n*n$.

The classic [sudoku puzzle](https://sudoku.com) is a $9*9$ grid that is divided into rows, columns and $9$ $3*3$ squares called a nonet, where:\

- Each column must contain the numbers $1-9$ without repetitions
- Each row must contain the numbers $1-9$ without repetitions
- Each nonet must contain the numbers $1-9$ without repetitions

Each puzzle is unique and has clues to solve the puzzle.
Which are numbers. According to [Cornell University](https://arxiv.org/abs/1201.0749) there is no way to solve a sudoku with only 16 clues.

So, if there is $x>16$ clues needed for a $9*9$ sudoku, what is the formula for how many are needed for a $n*n$ grid?

Comment: This might be a question for [Puzzling.SE](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 1):

If [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A198297) is to be taken as an authority, then no such formula exists that we humans know of. They only list the smallest number of clues for a puzzle to possibly have a unique solution for $1\times 1, 4\times 4$ and $9\times 9$ (and $0\times0$), and stop there. There is a bound on $16\times 16$, which lies somewhere between 15 clues and 55. If a formula were known, it would *probably* be mentioned on OEIS, and the solution would *probably* be known for more sizes.

In order to figure out that no 16-clue $3\times 3$ sudoku is uniquely solvable, they basically had to try to solve every single one. See, for instance, [this numberphile video](https://youtu.be/MlyTq-xVkQE) for more details on that feat. They *probably* wouldn't have needed that if a formula was known.

(Note that OEIS use $n^2\times n^2$ size sudokus, as the $n\times n$ size smaller boxes are laid out in an $n\times n$ grid. So they don't count, say, $2\times 2$ or $6\times 6$ as sudokus in this case.)

Comment: Note that it is next to impossible to conclusively claim that a formula doesn't exist, or that no formula has been found. That's why I present evidence instead of proof in this answer.